# Kile - different dictionaries for different documents

Tags: kile, spelling

I use Kile as my LaTex editor and sometimes I have to work in a project with three or four different languages. I have all dictionaries installed, but it seems impossible to set a specific dictionary to a particular document: it sticks to the default dictionary and I must change it manually every single time.

In my .kde/share/config/kilerc file it is possible to edit four options (`Bookmarks=`, `Highlighting=`, `Indentation Mode=`, `Mode=`) for every file, but there is no `Language=` option or something like that.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

---

Config:

- Kubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Kile 2.1.3